# Checkpoint multiple pyspark dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have some code that wraps a while loop inside another while loop (the algorithm it implements requires this structure unfortunately).

The dataframes used in the loops have super long lineages, so I'd like to use [`checkpoint`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67916597/dataframe-checkpoint-example-pyspark), to truncate their logical plans.

I have two questions:

1. If I checkpoint multiple dataframes (i.e., `df1.checkpoint()` and `df2.checkpoint()`), will they overwrite one another or are they checkpointed separately?
2. As I mentioned, the nature of my algorithm is iterative, so `df1.checkpoint()` will be executed multiple times. Does each execution write its own checkpoint or is the previous checkpoint overwritten at each step?

For context, my code looks something like this:

```py
sc.setCheckpointDir(PATH_CHECKPOINT)
df1 = spark.read.parquet(PATH_DF1)
df2 = spark.read.parquet(PATH_DF2)

_canIter, _iter = True, 0
while _canIter:

    df1 = transform(df1)
    df1.checkpoint()
    df2 = transform(df1)
    df2.checkpoint()

    _iter += 1
    _canIter = _iter < 3
```

Comment: dataframes are rdds, rdds are immutable -> your checkpoints will accumulate in a checkpointDir (in subdirs that looks like .../checkpointDir/<UUID>/rdd-1, .../checkpointDir/<same-UUID>/rdd-2, etc.)

Comment: You can checkpoint every nth time as well if it improves performance. Just use some mod arithmetic